# Cannot Login as any user other than Root - permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, login, root, strace

Help! I'm desperate :)

I can't login as any user other than root. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.

Here's command output:

```
root@pinky:~# adduser test
Adding user `test' ...
Adding new group `test' (1003) ...
Adding new user `test' (1003) with group `test' ...
Creating home directory `/home/test' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for test
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: Test User
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] 
root@pinky:~# su test
Cannot execute /bin/bash: Permission denied
root@pinky:~# su test -c touch thefile # Does nothing
root@pinky:~# strace -u test /bin/ls
execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls"], [/* 17 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFL)                     = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb771b000
_llseek(3, 0, 0xbfbbe4f8, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "strace: exec: Permission denied\n", 32strace: exec: Permission denied
) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb771b000, 4096)                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
root@pinky:~# ls -l /bin/ls
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 104528 2010-03-04 22:29 /bin/ls
```

You'll note that the permissions on /bin/ls are ridiculous. That's because I was trying to make sure there weren't any problems.

What's going on? Please, any suggestions are welcome! I don't know what to do!

Comment: First of all, don't go changing permissions on stuff (e.g. `ls`) out of desperation. What are the permissions and ownership on `/bin/bash`, `/etc/passwd`, `/home` and `/home/test`?

Comment: They're -rwxr-xr-x, owned by root. I've since changed permissions of ls back to the default, but adding extra permissions wouldn't hurt.

Comment: All of them? If `/home/test` is owned by root that may be most of your problem. Try `chown test:test /home/test`.

Comment: No, I meant the other things in /bin. Also, note the strace - it fails at opening the thing in /bin, not anything related to the home directory. The home directory of the test user is owned by test, as it should be.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/bin` itself? Without the execute bit for world, nobody will be able to seek in that directory.

Comment: Same. drwxr-xr-x.

Comment: What are the permissions on the dynamic loader (`/lib/ld-2.11.1.so`, or whatever `/lib/ld*` is a regular file) (and `/` and `/lib`)? Did you (perhaps accidentally) enable SELinux or AppArmor?

Comment: How did you manage to get logged in as root? Isn't the root account locked by default in Ubuntu?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: This is a server installation. It is either unlocked by default on Server Ubuntu, or I (or another sysadmin) have unlocked it in the past.

Comment: Gilles, I checked the permissions on that and they seem to be non-restrictive. Sadly the machine that was in question has gone down and I don't have physical access, but when I get it, thanks for the SELinux/AppArmor hint...

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as Dennis posted above in comments.  On ubuntu 10.04 there are some updates that cause the permissions on /bin to become 660 - which causes this problem.  Check that.

Comment: do you have a link for this info about the permissions on /bin?

Comment: This comes from personal experience, however a quick google search resulted this link which was the same thing I'm talking about: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1474880 - It's also just worth taking a look at all of the root directories, there are updates and installs that sometimes cause permissions to change on these which cause issues like this.

Comment: Dave that forum link just has further speculation. It would be useful to have some actual evidence that this was caused by an update of some kind. As a member of the ubuntu server team who triages server bugs every day, I'm surprised to hear of this for the first time.

Comment: SpamapS - it's been 6 months now so I don't remember all of the details.  I run a Ubuntu server at home and this exact thing happened to me after a large batch of updates.  Suddenly after restarting the system after the updates I could only log in as root, and after some digging I found that /bin was 660.  I can't tell you much more than that.

Comment: this answer has saved my ass. it turns out that on 10.10 there is also such problem